# How to avoid restarting macOS after running `defaults write LaunchServices LSHandlers`?

Tags: defaults, restart

I have changed default application opening specific file type using `defaults write` but for that to work I have to restart macOS. This feels unnecessary. Are there other options?

I've tried relaunching Finder, `sudo pkill -1 Dock`, and

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/\
lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

without success.

---

Example command to change default app:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.LaunchServices.secure LSHandlers\
 -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=public.shell-script;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.sublimetext.4;}'
```

Comment: If you are changing the default app in Finder's Get Info, you shouldn't need to restart.

Comment: I use `defaults write` command to edit a bunch of them.

Comment: Updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: Can you suply the complete command that you're using?

Comment: Update? On mobile atm so hard to type but you can see the last post on https://andrei.fokau.se

Comment: Log off and back on.

Comment: Logging off/on did not help. Does it work for you?

Comment: If you are changing the Plist file from app that is already loaded, you must restart to make it active